# How to get new access token from refresh token with googleapis npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I cannot seem to find an answer to this anywhere. All the docs say that refresh tokens are used to get new access tokens, but nowhere is it explained how this actually works.

Usually I would use this function accompanied by the code you get from the google consent page:
`oauth2Client.getToken(code)`.
So I would expect something like this:
`oauth2Client.getTokenWithRefreshToken(refresh_token)`.
But no.
Am I just misunderstanding the concept of refresh tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already had your refresh token and you want to use Google APIs using the access token retrieved from the refresh token using googleapis for Node.js, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  "###", // Please set your client ID.
  "###", // Please set your client secret.
  "###", // Please set your redirect uri.
);
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: "###" // Please set your refresh token.
});

// If you want to retrieve the access token from the refresh token, you can use the following sample script.
oauth2Client.getAccessToken((err, token) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(token);
});

// The following script is a sample script for using Drive API.
// In this case, it is required to include the scope for using Drive API. Please be careful this.
// const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: oauth2Client });
// drive.files.list({ pageSize: 10, fields: "files(name)" }, (err, res) => {
//   if (err) {
//     console.log(err);
//     return;
//   }
//   console.log(res.data);
// });
```

#### Reference:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: I've spent a week trawling through Google's documentation looking for some clue as to how to do this, [prompting someone else to escalate the situation](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/643)…