# Is there any googleapi, NOT RestAPI to refresh a user access token?

Tags: typescript, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

My Node.js app has the following lines to refresh access token of a user using RestAPI. It is working fine. But is there any Google API client library doing this, so that I don't need to deal with axios?

```
        const axiosResponse = await axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          data: {
            client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: await getSecret("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"),
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
          },
        });
        const newAccessToken = axiosResponse.data.access_token;
        return newAccessToken;
```

Comment: For example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71768135

Comment: @Tanaike The sample you shared requires clientID, clientSecret and redirectURL. However, if my code needs only the refreshToken we obtained in the process and request the updated a new access token from the end point, which is more streamlined. Hence, they may not using the same underlying RestAPI call.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the access token from only the refresh token. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike that is correct. I want to see if there us an googleapi to retrieve access token by only refresh token, which is the same way in my sample code using RestAPI. I want to switch using googleapi because I don't need to deal with axios and the future update is taken care by google.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, in order to retrieve the access token using the refresh token, it is required to use both the client ID and the client secret. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike So, is that mean the RestAPI example I provided above is the only way to retrieve an access token with solely a refresh token?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the script can be created freely. But, the request for retrieving the access token from the refresh token is the same.

Comment: @Tanaike, if you use the sample code I listed above, you will find out that access token can be retrieve by only refresh token, and it doesn't require any client ID nor client secret in that RestAPI. Hence, this way is different than the sample you shared which requires both client ID and client secret.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful. I would like to study more.

Comment: @CupidChan I don't understand how you say you're not using the client secret when you're passing `client_secret` one line above `refresh_token`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault @rhashimoto, `client_id` and `client_secret` are required in my example. But I don't need to provide redirect URL. Is there any way I can achieve that with googleapi?

Comment: @CupidChan You can do it with [OAuth2Client.getAccessToken](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/google-auth-library/oauth2client#google_auth_library_OAuth2Client_getAccessToken_member_1_). The [constructor](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/google-auth-library/oauth2client#google_auth_library_OAuth2Client_constructor_2_) for OAuth2Client takes a redirectUri argument, but it's optional. Construct it, then call setCredentials() with the refresh token, then getAccessToken().

Comment: It also appears that you can pass the undocumented string 'postmessage' as `redirect_uri` argument to functions that take one but don't actually need it, as discovered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74655776/1462337)